# How to source a file in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

jenkins version 2.249
i am using the jenkins pipeline where i have to source a file on one of my jenkins slave nodes.
I am able to cat the file inside the sh command but using "Source" command getting me an error "source: file.sh: file not found."

Comment: Check for the correct access permissions of the file.

Comment: i have given the permissions as 644. should i change it to something else

Comment: Try with 755 permissions and check.

Comment: tried with these permission but no luck. I tried with . ./file.sh inside the sh block but same thing.

Comment: I figured this out by using the single shell environment and use the commands in multi line string. sh block starts with ''' and ends with '''

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have entered a wrong directory and file.sh didn't appear there. So try use absolute path.

```bash
source /absolute/path/to/file.sh
```